# My BMW X5 won't stay running

Tags: engine, bmw, o2-sensor, motors

Hello I have a 2003 BMW X5. I just got the engine replace a couple days ago. I went to pick it up but because the shop was done installing the motor but now I have to deal with the other problems I had with the X5 before the motor went out.

I needed O2 sensors before but never got to it once the truck ran hot and I had to replace the motor. So what it's doing now is start off running good, then about 15 minutes in it starts to run really rough, gets loud, check engine light comes, it starts to sputter then turns off.

I got it a diagnostic and a couple codes came up. O2 sensor bank one, failsafe engine, mass airflow sensor etc. I had the O2 sensors replaced and it's still doing the same thing.

Somebody please help me I have already out over $6000 in the truck and I don't want to give up on it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I know you've mentioned the codes you're getting in general, but could you post the code descriptions exactly as they appear? Also, can you confirm that you didn't replace the mass air flow sensor(s)?

Comment: Please be careful. Whatever conditions that existed to kill your first engine may be killing your second engine. If a clogged cat, clogged injectors, bad ECU or other major issue was there before, it may still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon. Is there any smooth running contol light on when you run the test. If there is, you need to have a smooth running test to see where the injectors compensation is at. If there is No fault like that(control) you can check the air mass sensor by disconnecting it and see if it runs better

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).